# How to print text and variables in a single line

Tags: r

Is there a way to print text and variables in a single line in r

eg

```
a="Hello"
b="EKA"
c="123456"

print("$a !! my name is $b and my number is $c")
```

out put will be like this

```
Hello !! my name is EKA and my number is 123456
```

Comment: You can use `cat`: `cat(a, "!! my name is", b, "and my number is", c,"\n")`.

Comment: @Pascal thanks it worked

Comment: Could also do `print(paste(a, "!! my name is", b, "and my number is", c), quote = FALSE)` though not sure why the quotes so bothering you. Wouldn't `paste(a, "!! my name is", b, "and my number is", c)` be good enough too?

Comment: `sprintf("%s !! my name is %s and my number is %s", a, b, c)` too

Answer (score 26):

I'd suggest using sprintf function. The advantage of this function is, that the variables can be of any class (here, c is numeric).

```
a="Hello"
b="EKA"
c=123456

sprintf("%s !! my name is %s and my number is %i", a, b, c)
```

Comment: The variables can of any class in `cat` and `paste` too, not sure what are you trying to say here. Not to mention that that keeps the quotes which it seems like the OP trying to avoid.

Comment: @ David: Yes, the quoted string doesn't exactly match the OP's example. But when printing characters and numerics I prefer sprintf because of its possibilities to adjust how numbers are printed.

Comment: does this work inside functions though? If I'm not mistaken it only *returns* the string right?

Comment: @profPlum: The function returns "A character vector of length that of the longest input.". If you want the message to be printed to the console you can include it in a print() function.

Answer (score 2):

```
print( paste("You have choosen the following file name: ", fileName))
```

will do the job

Comment: Actually the following will do what u want: print(paste("",a,paste("my name is",b),"and my number is",c))

Comment: Edit your answer and include your comment and explain why it works.

Answer (score 2):

I like to do this: `print(c('x=',x))`
The output format is messy but all and all it is most convenient and flexible method I know (it works INSIDE FUNCTIONS unlike the `sprintf` solution & it can handle more data types too).

It is much faster to type than: `print(paste('x=',x))`.
Which is rather cumbersome for a simple print function!

Notable Alternative:
`cat('x=',x,'\n')`

I tend to avoid this also because I find it tedius to always specify the newline character. Although technically it was 'the function' that was invented to easily do what you are asking, it was designed poorly IMO.