# printing a paragraph in R

Tags: r

I have to report a bunch of basics statistical summaries from several simple datasets. Is there a way to write a function that would not only print out the mean, median, mode, kurtosis, etc., but also print out sentences, in a paragraph form that I can then copy and paste into the report?

Ideally, I'd want 2 vectors `x` and `y` to output something like this (shortened version):

> For Variable x, the mean is, mean(x), while the median is median(x). The highest of the values is max(x), and the min is min(x).

> The standard deviation is sd(x). The set of numbers has skew skew(x), and kurtosis kurtosis().

> For Variable y, the mean is, mean(y), while the median is median(y). The highest of the values is max(y), and the min is min(y).

> The standard deviation is sd(y). The set of numbers has skew skew(y), and kurtosis kurtosis()

EDIT:

After using the user's hint, I made something like this:

```r
make_paragraph <- function(v, w) {
  cat(
    "For vector a, values range from a low of ",min(v),
    "to a high of", max(v),
  
    ".The mean time is ", mean(v), 
    ", while the median is ", median(v), 
    ". We have a variance of", var(v),
    "and thus a standard deviation of", sd(v),
    ". The Inter Quartile Range is ", IQR(v), 
    ". A time value of",quantile(v,0.25),
    "marks the 25th percentile",quantile(v, .5),
    "marks the 50th percentile,",quantile(v, .75),
    "marks the 75th percentile. The kurtosis 
     is",kurtosis(v),
    "indication that time is.... The skewness number is",skew(v),
    "indicating that the distribution is ...."
     
    ".\n\n", sep=""
  )
  
  cat(
    "For women, values range from a low of ",min(w),
    "to a high of", max(w),
  
    ".The mean time is ", mean(w), 
    ", while the median is ", median(w), 
    ". We have a variance of", var(w),
    "and thus a standard deviation of", sd(w),
    ". The Inter Quartile Range is ", IQR(w), 
    ". A time value of",quantile(v,0.25),
    "marks the 25th percentile",quantile(v,0.5),
    "marks the 50th percentile,",quantile(v,.75),
    "marks the 75th percentile. The kurtosis is", kurtosis(v), 
    
    "indication that winning time is.... The skewness number is"
    ,skew(w),
    "indicating that the distribution is ...."
     
    ".\n\n", sep=""
  ) 
}
```

I just changed a few things yet I'm getting an error that says

```r
[1] "y"
For Variable c(1.5, -0.3, 12, 8.5, -100), the mean is -15.66, while the median is 1.5. The highest of the values is 12, and the min is -100.

Error in skew(v) : could not find function "skew"
[1] "For variable %f"
Error in print.default("The mean is, ", mean(x)) : invalid printing digits -15
Error: unexpected string constant in:
"     
    ".\n\n""
```

For the skew issue, I just need the correct package. What about the rest? What can I do?

Comment: How to print a mix of text and variable values is discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32241806/how-to-print-text-and-variables-in-a-single-line-in-r

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach based on function `strwrap`, which is designed for printing paragraphs and takes care of many formatting details for you.

The following function `f` accepts any number of numeric vectors and prints one paragraph for each supplied. The number of significant digits reported and the number of characters in a line are controlled by optional arguments `digits` and `width`.

```r
f <- function(..., digits = getOption("digits"), width = getOption("width")) {
  op <- options(digits = digits, width = width)
  on.exit(options(op))
  call <- match.call()
  call[c("digits", "width")] <- NULL
  f1 <- function(x, name) {
    paste0(
      "For variable `", name, "`, ",
      "the mean is ", format(mean(x)), ", while the median is ", format(median(x)), ". ",
      "The highest of the values is ", format(max(x)), " and the minimum is ", format(min(x)), ". ",
      "The standard deviation is ", format(sd(x)), "."
    )
  }
  l <- Map(f1, x = list(...), name = lapply(call[-1L], deparse), USE.NAMES = FALSE)
  s <- do.call(paste, c(l, list(sep = "\n\n")))
  writeLines(strwrap(s))
}
```

Here is a test with two numeric vectors `x` and `y`:

```r
set.seed(181818L)
x <- 1:10
y <- rnorm(10L)
f(x, y, digits = 4L, width = 72L)
```

```
For variable `x`, the mean is 5.5, while the median is 5.5. The
highest of the values is 10 and the minimum is 1. The standard
deviation is 3.028.

For variable `y`, the mean is -0.1395, while the median is
0.2025. The highest of the values is 0.9235 and the minimum is
-1.564. The standard deviation is 0.9332.
```

```r
f(x, y, digits = 6L, width = 60L)
```

```
For variable `x`, the mean is 5.5, while the median
is 5.5. The highest of the values is 10 and the
minimum is 1. The standard deviation is 3.02765.

For variable `y`, the mean is -0.139507, while the
median is 0.202508. The highest of the values is
0.923489 and the minimum is -1.56437. The standard
deviation is 0.933158.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function like this

```
make_paragraph <- function(v) {
  cat(
    "For Variable ", deparse(v), 
    ", the mean is ", mean(v), 
    ", while the median is ", median(v), 
    ". The highest of the values is ", max(v), 
    ", and the min is ", min(v), 
    ".\n\n", sep=""
  )

  cat(
    "The standard deviation is ", sd(v), 
    ". The set of numbers has skew ", skew(v), 
    ", and kurtosis ", kurtosis(v), 
    ".\n\n", sep=""
  )
}
```

Then all you have to do is call it:

```
x <- c(1.5, -0.3, 12, 8.5, -100)
make_paragraph(x)
```

Comment: You may also want to look into rmarkdown if you want more control over the formatting.

Comment: can you tell me more? What about markdown can I use? Im running my code inb a markdown file. Could you look at my edit to see what could be the problem?